# ADF Log analytics: TriggerRun correlation with ActivityRun

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

what im trying to achieve is to correlate to separate queries in Log analytics: TriggerRun with ActivityRun. I'm new using Kusto Queries.

when I query the ADFTriggerRun I get:
CorrelationId
TriggerId
trackingId

none of these are found when I run a query over on ADFActivityRun, the correlation Id doesnt match between these, or at least Im not entirely sure how to use this.

Any thoughts? Any Kusto Query that could give me a direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way how to connect ADFPipelineRun with ADFTriggerRun. Its not perfect but its starting to take shape. Maybe will help others.

```
ADFPipelineRun
| where condition contains "pipe_name"
| where format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'yyyy-M-d') has_any('2022-8-5','2022-8-4')
| project RunId,t=format_datetime(TimeGenerated,'yyyy-M-d'),TimeGenerated, OperationName,Category,CorrelationId,Level,Status,UserProperties,Annotations,Start,End,FailureType,PipelineName,Predecessors,Parameters,SystemParameters,Type
| join ( ADFActivityRun 
        | project RunId =PipelineRunId, TimeGenerated,OperationName, Category, CorrelationId,Level,Tags,Status,UserProperties,Annotations,Start,ActivityName,ActivityRunId,EffectiveIntegrationRuntime,ActivityType,ActivityIterationCount,End,FailureType,PipelineName,Input,Output,ErrorCode,ErrorMessage,Error,Type)
        on RunId
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no correlation between those IDs.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/41888

learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/38502/any-correlation-between-pipelineid-and-corelationi.html